# Need Help in Making Dynamic Sooql using Like Operator

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component, salesforce-id

I am trying to create Dynamic Soql Query using Like Operator given as below:

```
String tempInput ='\'%' + inputValue2  + '%\'';

                      soqlRAD2 = soqlRAD2  + ' and BR_Opportunity__r.Account.name Like :'+tempInput ;
```

But getting not able to format in properly and Getting Exception as below:

System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL.

Please Help me on this..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case

```
String tempInput ='\'%' + inputValue2  + '%\'';

soqlRAD2 = soqlRAD2  + ' and BR_Opportunity__r.Account.name Like :'+tempInput ;
```

Just remove colon **:**

like this

```
String tempInput ='\'%' + inputValue2  + '%\'';

soqlRAD2 = soqlRAD2  + ' and BR_Opportunity__r.Account.name Like '+tempInput ;
```

---

Example

```
system.debug(Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name like \'%test%\''));
```

With variable

```
String inputValue2 ='test';
system.debug(Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name like \'%' + inputValue2 + '%\''));
```